# Google Chrome Extension manifest.json file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm developing a Google Chrome Extension and facing a challenge with the background; the browser doesn't load the background picture added in CSS.

I can't seem to find an effective way to declare assets under the `web_accessible_resources` key in the `manifest.json` file.

What is the `manifest.json` file and how does one declare assets in it?

Comment: The `manifest.json` file is probably the single most important file in a chrome extension...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *manifest.json* file is required for any Chrome extension. The *manifest.json* file contains information that defines the extension. The format of the information in the file is [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

You can read more about what it contains in Google Chrome developer documentation: [Manifest File Format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest)

You will probably also want to read: [Overview of Google Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview)

A relatively simple *manifest.json* file looks like (source: [Getting Started: Building a Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

**[Manifest - Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources):**

This is an array of strings assigned to the key `web_accessible_resources` within your *manifest.json* file which specifies the assets within your extension that are to be made accessible by webpages. The file/path within *manifest.json* is relative to your extension's root directory.  The webpage can access the resource from a URL that looks like: `chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH]`.

Example (source:[Manifest - Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)):

```
{
  ...
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.png",
    "style/double-rainbow.css",
    "script/double-rainbow.js",
    "script/main.js",
    "templates/*"
  ],
  ...
}
```

For more information on `web_accessible_resources` see Google Chrome developer documentation: [Manifest - Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).